# Why does pg_restore take so much longer on Ubuntu than Windows?

Tags: windows, ubuntu, postgresql

I generated a dump file of 21 MB or so:

```
pg_dump --format=tar --verbose --file=database.backup mydatabase
```

When I import this file on windows doing:

```
pg_restore --dbname mydatabase --verbose database.backup
```

It takes 1 hour to be done.

Doing the same on Ubuntu 10.10 64bits boxes, takes about 7 hours!

Of course I'm talking about the same hardware specs (Dell Studio XPS). Same RAM, CPU, etc.

In both cases I'm using out of box configs for PostgreSQL 8.4.7.

Perhaps the distros configuration is different...
Perhaps some optimization that just windows distro is doing?

---

Extra info:
On Windows 7 -> NTFS. On Ubuntu 10.10 -> ext4

---

When I do

```
pg_dump --format=tar --verbose --file=workspace/work/dumps/loaded.backup mydb
```

I takes only 5 seconds! If I restore on an empty new db doing:

```
pg_restore --dbname mydb-2 --verbose workspace/work/dumps/loaded.backup
```

I takes only 10 seconds. (Problem solved?... almost)
It seems the db guys exported the original dump using different options. Perhaps --inserts option?

The big difference between Windows and Ubuntu using the original dump is still bothering my mind. Any thoughts on this?

Comment: Probably a better question for "those admin/server guys" ;-)

Comment: It'd be a good thing if you filed a bug report in Ubuntu's Launchpad, to get the right people to look at it.

Comment: dumb file, hehe ;)

Comment: @IErbaer: I fixed that, insulting your database backup tools is never a good idea.

Comment: Are you sure it is 21MB, and not 21GB? If it is 21GB then a difference can be explained if Windows does have hard drive write cache enabled and Linux does not. You can try start Postgres with `-F` (disable fsync) for duration of restore. If it really is 21MB then all I can say is that something is very, very wrong.

Comment: It is a 21 Mb dump.

Comment: I thnk your dump file is messed up, so why bother with windows vs ubuntu. If you restore a dump with --inserts it might be because of write-barrieres for ext4 behaves different than ntfs.. and look if some config params are different. But linux is better than windows if you are using postgresql.

Answer (score 4):

Even one hour is very long for a small dump file of 21 MB. We are restoring databases of 2 GB compressed dump file in about 30 minutes but we might have better hardware ;-)

What you should read first:

```
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/populate.html
```

It is all about your problem. It tells you how to poulate a database fast.

**Aditional** tips:

- **First enable logging of all statements with duration time and see what's going on**
- Increase shared_buffers, default on ubuntu 10.10 is only 24 MB, see http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/kernel-resources.html#SYSVIPC for configuring your linux system to accept higher values
- use --format=custom or -Fc for dumping. It's the best choice
- you can run pg_restore on multiple CPU with "-j" but i guess you have other problems that getting the last bits of performance

For further information:

- Read the excellent [online documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/)
- Buy [Postgresql 9.0 High Performance](http://www.amazon.de/PostgreSQL-High-Performance-Gregory-Smith/dp/184951030X/) (not regarding your problem, it is just an excellent book for experienced PostgreSQL DBA)

Answer (score 2):

**Edit:** I missed that you said the dump is merely 21MB, and not even compressed. Even 1 hour is a *very* long time to restore that amount of data. Could you shed some light on what the dump contains? What sort of table structure, how many indexes and what kind? Functional indexes? GiST/GIN indexes? How much data is generated after the dump is restored?

The PostgreSQL mailing list might be a better place to discuss this.

### Old post

The default PostgreSQL configuration is very conservative in terms of resource requirements. Which means that during bulk-loading, it has to perform very frequent checkpoints (your Postgres logs are probably full of checkpoint warnings).

I suspect that PostgreSQL on Windows might not correctly flush everything to disk, thus checkpoints don't affect performance much. If true, this is of course bad for database integrity.

If my assumptions are true, bumping `checkpoint_segments` up to 50 in the Ubuntu configuration should make it perform similarly to Windows. (There are lots of other tunables, but this is the most important one for bulk-loading)

Also, what does `SHOW wal_sync_method` say on your Ubuntu installation? It should be `fdatasync` for optimal performance, but some versions defaulted to `open_datasync`.

Comment: That still doesn't explain 7 hours to restore a 21 MB dump.

Comment: Oh sorry, I somehow missed the fact that it's 21 MB. Even 1 hour is *way* too long for that -- I'd expect 1 minute max. It would be interesting to hear what the dump contains?

Comment: Ok, I will detail some structures. (On original question).

Answer (score -1):

Try to turn autovacuum off in your postgresql.conf.

If that does not help, try defragmenting you disc...

Also, I wonder what was the filesystem in both cases?

Comment: On Windows7 -> NTFS. On Ubuntu 10.10 -> ext4